# Primitives and integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ is differentiable and $g$ admits a primitive function $G$ then any standard calculus book proves that $(g\circ f)\cdot f'$ has the primitive function $G\circ f$:$$\Bigg{[}\int g(x)dx\Bigg{]}_{x=f(t)}=\int g(f(t))f'(t)dt.$$

In the converse case when the right member of this equality exists, does the left member exist? I have never found any explicity proof of that... Thank you for any answer!

Comment: If $f$ is a constant function, then you don't get much information about $\int gdx$.

Comment: @T.A.E. Thank you very much... Jean Baptiste ;-)